# Small differences in data source can make quite a lot of difference?

Tags: time-series, t-test, least-squares

I got stuck in my econometrics problem, any idea/thought/help is highly appreciated.

I have 2 data sources, GVAR (noted with "Smith") and Macrobond. Both data cover almost the same time framework. If you have a look at the picture, you will see that graphs of the same variable from these two sources are almost identical. But when I regress, I get a completely different picture, the spread  (which I am interested in) is significant in one of them, while insignificant in the other. How could you explain it?

As I noticed, for GVAR data early periods weigh a lot more for the significance of the spread. By the way, the spread = long - short term interest rate

Another question, data to Q1-2017 is 01/01/2017 or 01/04/2017?

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]